# Setting up a sharepoint production sever 2013 - Setup account permmision level

Tags: 2013

I am using three accounts and 4 different severs for this environment.

**Accounts**
 - setup account 
 - farm account
 - service account

**Severs**
 - AppSever 
 - DBSever
 - etc....

When i try to create a farm in the app sever ( DB is created in the DB sever, logged into app sever with the setup account )
Whats are the permissions i should grant for the setup accout

So far i have given security admin + DB creater + DB owner (for master) but it says the current user does not have permission to connect to the DB

PS : I'm using scripts to create a farm

Comment: I found the solution Have to add DB owner for MODEL DB

Answer (score 2):

Please check the Technet documentaion for this information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx#Section2

I personaly put the setup account into an ad security group i later reuse as a global farm admins (high previleges for those guys). This group is local admin on all sharepoint related (most times even sql) boxes. On sql I grant the group SYSADMIN rights. That's just my config. Read the technet article to get the information needed for your environment.